# Reading string with comma as 'nan' from csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, dataset

My csv file which I try to read to data frame with pandas looks like:

```
Country Name    Country Code    Series Name                             Series Code
Afghanistan     AFG             Access to electricity (% of population) EG.ELC.ACCS.ZS
Albania         ALB             Life expectancy at birth, male (years)  SP.DYN.LE00.MA.IN
```

I opened it with the command:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=0, usecols=[2,3])
```

when this runs:

```
for index, row in frame.iterrows():
    if row[1] == 'SP.DYN.LE00.MA.IN':
        print("Sample ", row[0])
```

I get the output:

```
Sample nan
```

Sometimes it reads correctly the value in the column of "Series Name" but sometime not, as this "nan".
What should I do to make it read "Series Name" with commas as regularly?

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

I tried cleaning the file data from commas but it still doesn't work:

```
def cleanCommasFromCSV(path_old, path_new):
    with open(path_old, "r", newline="") as infile, open(path_new, "w", newline="") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(item.replace(",", "") for item in row)
```

Comment: Please post an example that reproduces your problem (see [MCVE]), and include your data as text, not as a picture.

Comment: @lanS Just did that. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't seem right. If `row[1] == 'SP.DYN.LE00.MA.IN'` then `print("Sample ", row[1])` should return `Sample SP.DYN.LE00.MA.IN`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you pinpoint the line that causes the problem?

Comment: @lanS My bad. fixed it

Comment: That's what I thought, the string contains the CSV separator `','`...

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30900541/5276797

Comment: @lanS But I don't want it to be splitted into 2 different rows as in the link

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the raw CSV file (at least the two rows in the example)?

Comment: @lanS Look at the second row of the data in the question please

Comment: So what's the separator in the file? Whitespace or tab?

Comment: Try `read_csv` with `sep='\s+'` or `delim_whitespace=True`.

Comment: @lanS Now i opened the file with note pad and its comma (the separator)

Comment: Why does the answer I linked to not work for you? Can you show the code you used to adapt it to your case?

Comment: @lanS Should i replace the semicols ; in your ling to commas?

And I want to save it to a good csv file, the link creates a dataframe

Comment: Yes, the link has the same problem except with semicolons. The answer also suggests a way of writing the CSV file properly afterwards.