# Pandas - How to remove quotes from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a CSV file and when I do

```
df.head()
```

I get the all the headers in the first cell and the data is one column long

Like:

```
"Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3", etc
"Data 1", "Date 2", "Data 3", etc
```

How do I remove the quotes and get the CSV to be one row and column per value instead of everything packed into one cell?

Here is the headers from the dataframe, but all of this is in one cell, not split out.

```
"EEID","Location","Company","SSN","First Name","Last Name","MI"
```

Comment: Example: `'   " wfwf  "  '.strip(' "')`. Gives `'wfwf'`. Does this helps?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the CSV file? There is probably a better way to do that while reading the file, instead of fixing it afterwards.

Comment: @ayhan The file looks sort of like the example from pandas. All data is in quotes then it goes to the next field.

Comment: @Elmex80s That makes sense. What would be the logic to run something like that for each column of the file?

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: @Elmex80s I have updated the original post. I'm not sure how to get it to copy over exactly from Jupyter notebook, but basically all the data that is in rows in the CSV is going into it's own cell. So my dataframe is one column by however many rows in the file. Also, the quotes show up when I view the CSV in Notepad ++

Comment: I've already done some experiments.  The problem is, I can come up with several scenarios that reproduce your dataframe.  I'm not going to guess which one is yours.  The only way for me to know how to solve your problem is for you to share the contents of the actual file.  Not the dataframe... the file.  Also, would be nice to see what you used to import as well.

Comment: @piRSquared I'm using pd.read_csv('file.csv','tab name', na_values=['NA'])

Comment: OK, maybe I misinterpreted it, you want to go form a .csv to a DataFrame where the ros and columns are as expected.

Comment: @Elmex80s That's correct.

Comment: Read_csv has so many options, (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). What about the `quotechar` parameter?

Comment: @Elmex80s using quotechar along with skipinitialspace got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How do you read in the CSV file to the pandas dataframe?
The function

```
pandas.read_csv()
```

has many parameters. This might be solved by changing the default value of the parameter delimiter (delimiter=None). See the official pandas documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

This example might be similar (but we require test code of your CSV file to know for certain):

[python pandas read_csv delimiter in column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898935/python-pandas-read-csv-delimiter-in-column-data)