# Pandas does not consider separator - utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import

Good evening,

I am trying to import a dataset from a txt file using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep= ";", encoding = "latin1")
```

But it creates one single column(instead of several ones), as it follows:

```
print(df.head())

col1;col2;col3;col4; (...)

000003;2017;01;02;08;39;13;04;01;020582033    ;V1;T;00001;E;0000011900;000000000;10;01;L   ; ;             ;00001;00000;venp2010;ant;00000; ;S;000001         ; ;     product300MG 3ML
```

Unfortunately, my dataset is 245mb and Excel does not allow me to open the file to convert it.

If it try to import it using(cfr. [python pandas read_csv delimiter in column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898935/python-pandas-read-csv-delimiter-in-column-data)):

```
with open(path, "r", newline="") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=";")
    rows = [x[:1] + [';'.join(x[1:-2])] + x[-2:] for x in reader] 
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

It reports the following error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 136: invalid continuation byte
```

How can i fix this issue, in order to import it properly?

Comment: Could you please be more specific, in terms of the code of the link I should use? Thank you @RCA

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate because my guess is that this is an issue with quoting. The answer for the question has information about how to read the file so that those issues are resolved.

Comment: if I try to use that code, it gives me the following error:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 136: invalid continuation byte    @RCA

Comment: @allesandro-ceccarelli You'd need to include the encoding in the open statement: `with open('some.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='latin1') as f:`

Comment: even if I add that, it does not separate all the columns, splitting in just three of them @RCA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168748/discussion-between-rca-and-alessandro-ceccarelli).